# ActiveModel: Validate Value for Equality

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activemodel

I have an *ActiveModel* class whose instances should only be valid if they have been touched. The following code works:

```
class Base
  include ActiveModel::Model
  validates :touched?, inclusion: { in: [true] }

  def update(params = {})
    initialize(params)
    @touched = true
  end

  def touched?
    !!@touched
  end
end
```

But I don't like it. It's not nice. I'd like to write something like that:

```
validates: touched?, equality: true
```

Is there a better/shorter way of writing that without using a custom validator? Would be nice if it worked also for values other than *booleans*.

Answer (score 5):

```
validates :touched?,  acceptance: true
```

Comment: `:acceptance` does't work if there isn't an `attr_reader` for `touched?`. I've updated the class above with more information which seems to be relevant.

Comment: @schmijos, what values of \@touched might be?

Comment: The two values possible now are `true` and `nil`. The validation should only pass on `true`.

Comment: if you have touched? method, you might use custom validation, `validate :touched?`